# Video playback is messed up

Tags: nvidia, firefox, video, vlc

I have a new dual-boot install of Kubuntu 23.10 and Windows 11. This machine has an NVIDIA GTX1650 graphics card. Playback of videos is problematic. MP4 videos will play in Dragonplayer and VLC (but not other players), but with no sound. Youtube videos in Firefox only show the first frame and then freeze with a spinning circle. I hate to say it, but everything works fine in Windows 11. Can anyone point me in a direction to try and resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Edit - I loaded up the Live ISO of Kubuntu 23.10 on this machine and all video/sound content works fine.

Edit #2 - I blew away the partition and reinstalled Kubuntu 23.10. On the fresh install video playback worked fine and I set about "moving in" to the new machine. Then I thought to check video playback again and... same problem.

Comment: try gnome video app (totem)